# How to get results from a grid field in low search

Tags: grid, low-search, low

I have the field for my grid marked as searchable and the interior fields marked searchable and added to a collection, but I can't get anything inside the grid to show up on a search... I've kept it super simple:

```
{exp:low_search:results
    query="{segment_3}"
    limit="10"
    paginate="bottom"
}
```

Both of my other collections return the right results...

Answer (score 3):

Did you mark the Grid field as searchable *after* creating entries? If so, you need to re-save those entries in order to populate the `exp_channel_data` table with searchable data, which Low Search in turn uses for its collection index.