# Getting meaningful search results from a Grid field

Tags: search, grid, simple-search

I have a channel that is used for the creation of a glossary. Rather than creating numerous individual entries, I have chosen to build the glossary as a Grid field (called 'glossary'), with the channel itself set as a Single Entry channel (using the [Single Entry add-on](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/single-entry)).

The field (and its columns) are searchable, and matches are being found by my Simple Search form correctly. However, displaying the search results is problematic. The Search results are seemingly unable to determine which row of the Grid field the match occurs in, and the result simply displays the first row.

I guess that what I need is for the {exp:search:search_results} tag to return the {glossary:field_row_count} variable for the search match, so that I can make use of it in my results code.

Is there any way to do this? Or an alternative solution/workaround? (I'd prefer to stick with the native EE Search features if possible, rather than involve yet another third party add-on).

[Using EE v2.9.2]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I never answered this earlier, but we've had a duplicate question that I've posed an answer too here :

[Grid and Search Results](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13986/grid-and-search-results/31461#31461)

Perhaps this might help if this quesion is not too stale??